# Send a raw HTTP request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am looking for a way to send raw HTTP requests, i.e. from a string containing the full request. It seems `XmlHttpRequest` does not provide such a method.

My final need is to "forward" HTTP requests by executing them and receiving their answers as a string too.

Any idea of what could I use ?

Comment: @JulioGurrera     Can you not use any plugin for sending HTTP raw requests? Mozilla has some plugins like that.

Answer (score 1):

[Chrome Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/) can open a TCP connection with [chrome.socket](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html), and you can send raw requests.

Comment: To clarify, this option is available if you're a Chrome app. The original question isn't detailed enough to tell whether that is an option.

Comment: This would partially work since TCP connection properties will depend on the request and even answers. It would work for simple requests.